# How to pass a template variable to event handler method in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This code:

```
<tbody v-for="contact in contacts">
    <tr v-on:click="selectContact(1)">
```

is working well in Vue js.

But this:

```
<tbody v-for="contact in contacts">
    <tr v-on:click="selectContact({{contact.index}})">
```

Doesn't seem to work well. Resulting in an error. So how can I pass a environmental variable like contact.index into the event method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tbody v-for="contact in contacts">
    <tr v-on:click="selectContact(contact.index)">
```

or simply

```
<tbody v-for="contact in contacts">
    <tr @click="selectContact(contact.index)">
```

`v-on` directive will evaluate the string as an expression. You don't have to insert extra `{{ }}`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Leo's answer, if you are looking for getting index of v-for loop than you have to do following:

```
<tbody v-for="(contact, index) in contacts">
    <tr v-on:click="selectContact(index)">
```

Comment: Absolutely. Check out **example 2** in the doc http://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Basic-Usage

Answer (score 1):

Second code resulting error that is related to interpolation

```
<tbody v-for="contact in contacts">
    <tr v-on:click="selectContact({{contact.index}})">
```

Why this happening ? Because you are using templating part `{{}}` into `v-on:click` directive, which VueJS see as normal aka vanilla JS, so it can't accept the templating here `{{}}` - mustaches.

Previous answers give you correct and working solutions.